# flutter release version launcher icon

Tags: flutter, dart

I build an application I did all the testing and everything was fine in debug mode. But after uploading the app in Playstore app launcher icon is not changed and the default flutter icon is being displayed. I have changed with my logo's in app>src>main>res as well.

```
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
```

Comment: Please check in Android manifest.xml and check icon tag

Comment: icon path in manifest is fine, replaced default  icons with mine debug version is working fine.  only in release build app icon is not changed.

Comment: please check in Android Studio app/gradle file maybe buildeType release part icon setting wrong

Comment: can you please elaborate this. I did not understand clearly what has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be because I used same debug mobile, downloaded app from playstore. In all other devices app launcher icon is working fine.